# Simple function display only home page

Tags: wordpress, filter, action

I have a simple function that I need to assign to a hook, and then have it appear only on the home page.

I just cannot seem to get it right.

```
add_action( 'woo_content_before', 'woo_add_home_slider' );

function woo_add_home_slider () {
    if ( function_exists( 'soliloquy_slider' ) ) soliloquy_slider( '169' ); 
}
```

I need this to only show on my homepage.

Answer (score 2):

To make your function display only on the home page, you would use the WordPress function [is_home()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_home) and/or [is_front_page](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_front_page), depending on your home page settings.

If your home page is set to list your blog posts, then this would be your solution:

```
function woo_add_home_slider() {
    if (is_home()) {
        if ( function_exists( 'soliloquy_slider' ) ) soliloquy_slider( '169' ); 
    }
}
```

If your home page is set to display a specific page:

```
function woo_add_home_slider() {
    if (is_front_page()) {
        if ( function_exists( 'soliloquy_slider' ) ) soliloquy_slider( '169' ); 
    }
}
```

Or, depending on your settings, you might be able to get the effect you want by combining the two with an or:

If your home page is set to list your blog posts, then this would be your solution:

```
function woo_add_home_slider() {
    if (is_home() || is_front_page()) {
        if ( function_exists( 'soliloquy_slider' ) ) soliloquy_slider( '169' ); 
    }
}
```

Of course, you could combine the ifs into a single condition, like so:

```
function woo_add_home_slider() {
    if ((is_home() || is_front_page()) && function_exists( 'soliloquy_slider' )) {
        soliloquy_slider( '169' ); 
    }
}
```